# como obtener datos anidados en json con getters y setters

Tags: java, android, json

Tengo el siguiente Json:

```
"matrix": {
"id": 5926,
"name": "matriz fransico zarco",
"friendly_url": "matriz-fransico-zarco",
"headquarter": true,
"user_id": null,
extra_services": [
  0{
"id": 5,
"service_name": "Presupuesto Gratis",
"created_at": "2016-05-18T12:08:12.000-05:00",
"updated_at": "2016-05-18T12:08:12.000-05:00",
"icon": ""
}],
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYpXz.jpg captura del json
y quiero acceder a lo que seria extra services y obtener **service_name** se como traerme lo que serian los campos de id, name, friendly_url que estan directos en matrix pero no tengo idea como hacerlo cuando estan anidados, muchas gracias por su ayuda

**EDIT**

Actualmente obtengo lo que  quiero por medio de  una clase modelo en la que tengo getters y setters de lo que quiero
**Business.java**

```
public class Business {

    private Integer id, subcategory_id, business_package_id,rating;
    private String name, description, email, website, logo_url_string, icon_default,business_name,icon,cover_default,cover_url_string,extra_services;
    private Boolean status;


    public Business(){}

    public Business(Integer id, Boolean status, Integer subcategory_id, Integer business_package_id,Integer rating,String business_name, String name, String description, String email, String website, String logo_url_string, String cover_default, String icon, String icon_default,String cover_url_string,String extra_services) {

        this.id = id;
        this.icon=icon;
        this.status = status;
        this.subcategory_id = subcategory_id;
        this.business_package_id = business_package_id;
        this.name = name;
        this.business_name=business_name;
        this.description = description;
        this.email = email;
        this.website = website;
        this.logo_url_string = logo_url_string;
        this.rating=rating;
        this.icon_default=icon_default;
        this.cover_default=cover_default;
        this.extra_services=extra_services;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getRating() {
        return rating;
    }

    public void setRating(Integer rating) {
        this.rating = rating;
    }


    public String getBusiness_name() {
        return business_name;
    }
```

no pongo todo el código por que pues es todo, o sea son puros getters y setters.
Después esos getters los mando a llamar en un adapter y el adapter lo pongo en un `recyclerview` es por eso que no podia poner todo el código, lo hago de esta forma

```
 holder.mTitle.setText(businessList.get(position).get_name());
```

donde holder es un ViewHolder y le quiero poner el texto de lo que tenga el adapter en la posicion y le digo que obtenga el nombre 
eso es lo que quiero hacer pero pues no se como por que pues esta anidado **service_name** espero con eso haya quedado un poco mas claro y el json lo copie tal cual de un http requester es de un api, no lo pongo completo por que es muy largo, muchas gracias por su ayuda :D

Comment: Muestra lo que has hecho hasta, ahora? como mappeaste el json? Lo que tienes ahi es una estructura anidada, debes crearte otra clase modelando lo que hay en extra_services y luego en tu getter poner `List<ServicioData>` siendo `ServicioData` la clase que te hayas creado

Comment: bueno no conosco bien bien android pero para hacer múltiples request al servidor o hacer un mapeo del Json podrias utilizar Observables con su metodo flatMap o concatMap segun cual sea tu requisito.

Comment: Agrega el json completo, no se sabe si es un json Array o json Object. @Hebersolis

Comment: actualice mi duda :) muchas gracias

Comment: Te recomiendo que te mires la librería Gson

Comment: Jaja es la que estoy usando, pero es que necesito hacerlo con getters y setters, no una librería no declarando como json array ni como json object...necesito acceder con getters y setters

Comment: @HeberSolis volcas el json con gson hacia el objeto y desde allí usas los setters y getters del objeto. puedes usar la siguiente herramienta http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: muchas gracias si era asi como tu dijiste! :D

Answer (score -1):

Debes revisar el .json para determinar si es un objeto Json o un Arreglo Json:

> Si el .json inicia con `{` se considera como objeto Json.

Usas la clase `JSONObject` para obtener el objeto:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(contenidoJSON);
```

> Si el .json inicia con `[` es considerado como Arreglo Json.

Por lo tanto usarìas la clase `JSONArray`:

```
 JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(contenidoJSON);
```

Comment: si eso si lo se jeje, actualice mi duda por aquello de que no haya quedado muy claro cual es mi problema, muchas gracias

Comment: Si sabes lo que comento entonces sin problema podrìas realizar lo que comentas en tu pregunta : **y quiero acceder a lo que seria extra services y obtener service_name se como traerme lo que serian los campos de id, name, friendly_url que estan directos en matrix pero no tengo idea como hacerlo cuando estan anidados** .

Comment: agregue una captura del json, jaja es que si fuera tan sencillo ya me hubiera salido,actualice tambien mi duda, con gson es muy facil hacer eso directamente get as jsonarray y get as json object y se acabo, pero el problema es que quiero hacerlo con getters y setters no directamente, por eso te digo que eso si lo se

Comment: Si dan -1 al menos comentar la razòn!